# Сортировка выбором массива объектов по убыванию

Tags: java, сортировка, сортировка-выбором

Помогите пожалуйста. Пытаюсь сделать сортировку выбором массива объектов по убыванию, через `compareTo`, цикл и `if` но сортировка не получается.

Класс `Car`:

```java
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    private String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car car) {
        return (this.name.compareTo(car.name));
    }
}
```

Класс `Main`:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car[] cars = new Car[7];

        cars[0] = new Car("Skoda");
        cars[1] = new Car("FIAT");
        cars[2] = new Car("FORD");
        cars[3] = new Car("MAN");
        cars[4] = new Car("KIA");
        cars[5] = new Car("BMW");
        cars[6] = new Car("LADA");

        Car max = new Car("");
        Car max1 = new Car("");

        for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            max = cars[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < cars.length; j++) {
                int q = max.compareTo(cars[j]);
                if (q <= 0) {
                    max = cars[j];
                    max1 = cars[i];
                    cars[j] = max1;
                    cars[i] = max;
                } else if (q > 0) {
                    max = cars[i];
                    max1 = cars[j];
                    cars[i] = max1;
                    cars[j] = max;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cars[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что такое "сортировку выбором массива объектов по убыванию". вы просто пытаетесь отсортировать обекты в массиве? тогда никакой цикл не нужен вообще

Answer (score 1):

Так думаю отсортируется

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car[] cars = new Car[7];

    cars[0] = new Car("Skoda");
    cars[1] = new Car("FIAT");
    cars[2] = new Car("FORD");
    cars[3] = new Car("MAN");
    cars[4] = new Car("KIA");
    cars[5] = new Car("BMW");
    cars[6] = new Car("LADA");

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cars.length - i - 1; j++) {
        int q = cars[j].compareTo(cars[j + 1]);
        if (q < 0) {
          Car temp = cars[j + 1];
          cars[j + 1] = cars[j];
          cars[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(cars[i]);
    }
  }
```

выхлоп такой

```
{name='Skoda'}
{name='MAN'}
{name='LADA'}
{name='KIA'}
{name='FORD'}
{name='FIAT'}
{name='BMW'}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [Сортировка выбором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC/info) ([Selection sort](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selection-sort/info)) массива строк по убыванию

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] cars = {"FIAT", "FORD", "MAN", "KIA", "BMW", "LADA"};
    // сортировка выбором по убыванию
    selectionSort(cars);
    // вывод
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cars));
    // [MAN, LADA, KIA, FORD, FIAT, BMW]
}
```

```java
// сортировка выбором по убыванию
public static void selectionSort(String[] array) {
    // обход всех подмножеств элементов массива
    // (1-последний, 2-последний, 3-последний, ...)
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        // установить текущий элемент как максимум
        int max = i;
        // обход последующих элементов
        // чтобы найти наибольший
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            // если этот элемент больше,
            // тогда это новый максимум
            if (array[j].compareTo(array[max]) > 0) {
                max = j;
            }
        }
        // если максимальный элемент не равен
        // текущему, тогда поменять их местами
        if (max != i) {
            String temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[max];
            array[max] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы так настойчиво снова и снова предлагаете правку краткого описания двух меток, что решился обратить ваше внимание на [соответствующий раздел справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts). пока предлагаемое вами краткое описание будет лишь повторять то, о чём эта метка, **вместо инструкции по применению метки**, ваша правка будет вновь и вновь отклоняться.